# /#!/ url segment in Nodejs MEAN Stack (Mean.io) clean install

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I've cloned, installed a fresh version of the MEAN stack from https://github.com/linnovate/mean, and then ran with grunt.

I've noticed that my root page is appending a `/#!/` url segment to the end, and all my pages look something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/#!/
http://localhost:3000/#!/articles/
...
```

Any hints on how to get rid of that `/#!/`url segment? I can't tell if this is a Node/Angular/Express setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in Angular.js and it is commented in the file on github as to why it is there

https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/public/js/init.js

```
'use strict';
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {    
//Fixing facebook bug with redirect   
   if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') window.location.hash = '#!';    //Then init the app        angular.bootstrap(document, ['mean']);
 });
```

Although I do not claim to understand why not having it would cause an issue and I'm not sure why it presents itself on every page?